# loop in c with unkown times of loops

Tags: c

I want ot make a programme that will ask for a postive number n and then will make n loops and then the user will put n numbers and find the average. I have gone this far but it dosen't stop within the n loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, n;
  float sub, k;
  printf("Give a positive number\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  while (n < 0) {
    printf("Wrong number try again\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  }
  for (i = 0; i = n; i++) {
    printf("Give a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &sub);
    k = k + sub;
  }
  printf("\n%f", sub / n);
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i = n; i++)` should probably be `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: `i = n` -> `i < n`.

Comment: enable warning on your favorite compiler next time !

Comment: Also, `scanf("%d", &sub)` is wrong.  Needs to be `scanf("%f", &sub)`.  (A good compiler would have warned you about that, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is incorrect, this:

```
for (i = 0; i = n; i++) {
    printf("Give a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &sub);
    k = k + sub;
  }
```

Sets `i` = `n`, which doesn't do a comparison, it is an assignment. Enabling compiler warnings would probably tell you that you are using an unintended assignment. What you really want is a comparison:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Give a number\n");
    scanf("%f", &sub);
    k = k + sub;
  }
```

Comment: Your last sentence is perfect to confuse anybody ;)

Comment: @Stargateur I removed it, it is confusing, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

as loop condition and *k* instead of *sub* as the sum of the elements

```
printf("\n%f", k / n);
```

Edit:
Use *%f* to read float with scanf:

```
scanf("%f", &sub);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 2 faults:

- `for (i = 0; i = n; i++)`: in `i = n` you are assigning to `i` the value of `n`, you are not comparing them. Use instead: `i < n`
- `scanf("%d", &sub);`: You are picking up a digit. How `sub` is a float variable, you should pick up a float, not a digit. Use instead: `scanf("%f", &sub);`

Here is working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, n;
  float sub, k;
  printf("Give a positive number\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  while (n < 0) {
    printf("Wrong number try again\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Give a number\n");
    scanf("%f", &sub);
    k = k + sub;
  }
  printf("\n%f", sub / n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

•first thing, you should initialize k to 0 : `float sub, k=0;` .
•then, change `for (i = 0; i = n; i++)` to `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` because `i = n` is not a condition.
•finally, print the right average : use `printf("\n%f", k / n);` but not `printf("\n%f", sub / n);` .

Good Luck :)